# Looking for software tool to generated bar chart and merge with infographics

Tags: images

I am looking for software to create bar and other graphs such as line and scatter plots that can be easily combined with infographics similar to this example.  I am only familiar with Office software and Matlab graphics.

[image: Bar Chart Infographic]